# Keras custom function: implementing Jaccard

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am trying to apply the Jaccard coefficient as customised loss function in a Keras LSTM, using Tensorflow as backend.

I know the I have to call the following:

```python
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss=[jaccard_similarity])
```

where jaccard_similarity function should be the keras.backend implementation of the below:

```python
def jaccard_similarity(doc1, doc2):
   intersection =set(doc1).intersection(set(doc2))
   union = set(doc1).union(set(doc2))
   return len(intersection)/len(union)
```

The problem is that I cannot find methods to implement intersection and union functions on tensors using tensorflow as backend.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've used the jaccard distance to train a semantic segmentation network in keras. The loss function I used is identidical to [this one](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-contrib/blob/master/keras_contrib/losses/jaccard.py). I'll paste it here:

```
from keras import backend as K
def jaccard_distance(y_true, y_pred, smooth=100):
    intersection = K.sum(K.abs(y_true * y_pred), axis=-1)
    sum_ = K.sum(K.abs(y_true) + K.abs(y_pred), axis=-1)
    jac = (intersection + smooth) / (sum_ - intersection + smooth)
    return (1 - jac) * smooth
```

Notice that this one minus the jaccard similarity (which you want to maximize). In fact, it's a continuous approximation of the jaccard distance, so it's derivative is well defined.

Answer (score 12):

Careful with [Artur's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49290815/7109848) answer!

> ```
> intersection = K.sum(K.abs(y_true * y_pred), axis=-1)
> sum_ = K.sum(K.abs(y_true) + K.abs(y_pred), axis=-1)
> ```

Loss function in the link is incorrect! 
|X| denotes the cardinality of the set, not the absolute value! Also the summation runs through classes ?

The corrected version should look something like this: (tensorflow version, not tested yet)

```
def jaccard_distance(y_true, y_pred, smooth=100):
    """ Calculates mean of Jaccard distance as a loss function """
    intersection = tf.reduce_sum(y_true * y_pred, axis=(1,2))
    sum_ = tf.reduce_sum(y_true + y_pred, axis=(1,2))
    jac = (intersection + smooth) / (sum_ - intersection + smooth)
    jd =  (1 - jac) * smooth
    return tf.reduce_mean(jd)
```

Inputs are image tensors of shape (batch, width, height, classes).
Calculates the jaccard distance for each batch and class (shape=(batch, classes)) and returns mean value as a loss scalar.

Comment: I don't think the `tf.abs(.)` changes much unless labels are negative.  It is directly to tensors, not in the middle of some operation. But good point. (tf.abs(A+B) is different than (tf.abs(A) + tf.abs(B))

Answer (score 0):

As I see, there is a [sets section](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/sets) in TF v1.6 docs. Probably that could help. It contains a couple of functions that compute set intersection, difference and union.

Not sure though when it was introduced and if it is possible to somehow "hack" Keras models to use a custom metric with these functions.